# How to get formatted SQL query result

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider this a table

```
Code Name   City    Salary
---------------------------
1   Mark    LA      12000
2   Selena  NY       6000
3   Justin  USA     50000
4   John    CN       3000
```

I want result like this

```
John lives in `CN` and his salary is 3000.
Justin lives in `USA` and his salary is 50000.
```

How can I do so in Oracle?

If there is different method then explain them also .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your homework, dude?

Comment: ok for homework, but you should at least do some search and attempts before posting a question. An [hint](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators003.htm#SQLRF51158)

Comment: You need to it by yourself, just try it! It's not so difficult: SELECT * FROM and so on. If you get a troubles, come back and we'll help you.

Comment: thanks Alekse i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate values in SQL you use `||`. Character values are supplied using single quotes: `'`.

Putting that together you need to use:

```
select name ||' lives in "'||city||'" and his/her salary is '||salary
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can create and call a procedure.

In procedure, you can make if else conditions according to  your requirement and add queries like :

```
select (Name || ' lives in '|| City || 'and his/her salary is' || Salary || '.') from tablename;
```

Comment: This is not Oracle

Comment: @AkAsh: why are you asking for mysq? You tagged your question with `oracle`

Comment: you first asked for oracle,if u need mysql just use concat() method instead of ||

Comment: for oracle i got my solution just curious weather it will work or not,  plus its a good thing to learn

Comment: for mysql just use concat() method